# GDAX/Coinbase API Level3 orderbook - skipping messages

Tags: c#, websocket, coinbase-api, gdax-api, websocket-sharp

I'm using the GDAX API [Websocket Stream](https://docs.gdax.com/#the-code-classprettyprintfullcode-channel) to try and create a copy of the full LEVEL3 orderbook.

I've got a very simple implementation using WebSocketSharp and Im basically doing something like this.

```
private readonly WebSocket _webSocket = new WebSocket("wss://ws-feed.gdax.com");

_webSocket.OnMessage += WebSocket_OnMessage;
_webSocket.Connect();
_webSocket.Send(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new BeginSubscriptionMessage()));

private void WebSocket_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseMessage>(e.Data);
    switch (message.Type)
    {   
        case "match": //A trade occurred between two orders. 
            MatchMessage matchMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MatchMessage>(e.Data);
            _receivedMatchQueue.Enqueue(matchMessage);
            break;
        case "received": //A valid order has been received and is now active. This message is emitted for every single valid order as soon as the matching engine receives it whether it fills immediately or not.
            ReceivedMessage receivedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReceivedMessage>(e.Data);
            _receivedMessageQueue.Enqueue(receivedMessage);
            break;
        case "open": //The order is now open on the order book. This message will only be sent for orders which are not fully filled immediately. remaining_size will indicate how much of the order is unfilled and going on the book.
            OpenMessage openMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenMessage>(e.Data);
            _receivedOpenQueue.Enqueue(openMessage);
            break;
        case "done": //The order is no longer on the order book. Sent for all orders for which there was a received message. This message can result from an order being canceled or filled. 
            DoneMessage doneMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DoneMessage>(e.Data);
            _receivedDoneQueue.Enqueue(doneMessage);
            break;
        case "change": //Existing order has been changed
            ChangeMessage changeMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChangeMessage>(e.Data);
            _receivedChangeQueue.Enqueue(changeMessage);
            break;
        case "activate": //Stop order placed
            //Console.WriteLine("Stop Order Placed");
            //ActivateMessage activateMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActivateMessage>(e.Data);

            break;
        case "subscriptions":
            break;
        case "ticker":
            TickerMessage tickerMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TickerMessage>(e.Data);
            _receivedTickerQueue.Enqueue(tickerMessage);
            break;
        case "l2update":

            break;
    }
}
```

The problem I am running into is that when I look at the sequence numbers as received through both the RECEIVED and OPEN messages I can see they are not sequential which ([based on the following information](https://docs.gdax.com/#sequence-numbers)) suggests that messages are being skipped.

Basically you end up with something like this

```
Open Message SequenceId: 5359746354
Open Message SequenceId: 5359746358
Open Message SequenceId: 5359746361
Open Message SequenceId: 5359746363
Open Message SequenceId: 5359746365
Open Message SequenceId: 5359746370
Open Message SequenceId: 5359746372
```

I have tried testing this on Azure, just to make sure that it wasn't a bandwidth limitation on my end and the results were largely similar.

So given this, how is it possible to build a complete 'real-time' orderbook using the 'full' websocket stream if messages are dropped? Can I just safely ignore them? Or do I just somehow clear orphaned values?

Any advice from anyone having done something similar would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely messages are not dropped, you just have wrong impression of what "sequence" those sequence numbers represent.

As stated in api documentation

> Most feed messages contain a sequence number. Sequence numbers are
>   increasing integer values **for each product** with every new message
>   being exactly 1 sequence number than the one before it.

So every channel has separate sequence number for each product (like `ETH-USD`), not for each message type (like "open" or "receive"). Suppose you subscribed to "full" channel, for products `ETH-USD` and `ETH-EUR`. Then you should expect sequence like this:

```
receive `ETH-EUR` X
open `ETH-EUR` X + 1
receive `ETH-USD` Y
done `ETH-EUR` X + 2
open `ETH-USD` Y + 1
```

For full channel, message types are: received, open, done, match, change, activate (note that ticker message belongs to different channel, so has separate sequence). So to ensure no messages are not skipped you need to track all those message types and ensure that last sequence number you received is exactly 1 less than new sequence number, per product (in case you subscribed to multiple products).

Proof code:

```
class Program {
    private static readonly WebSocket _webSocket = new WebSocket("wss://ws-feed.gdax.com");
    private static long _lastSequence = 0;
    private static readonly HashSet<string> _expectedTypes = new HashSet<string>(
        new[] { "received", "open", "done", "match", "change", "activate" });

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var subMsg = "{\"type\": \"subscribe\",\"product_ids\": [\"ETH-USD\"],\"channels\": [\"full\"]}";
        _webSocket.OnMessage += WebSocket_OnMessage;
        _webSocket.Connect();
        _webSocket.Send(subMsg);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }        

    private static void WebSocket_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e) {
        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseMessage>(e.Data);
        if (_expectedTypes.Contains(message.Type)) {
            lock (typeof(Program)) {
                if (_lastSequence == 0)
                    _lastSequence = message.Sequence;
                else {
                    if (message.Sequence > _lastSequence + 1) {
                        Debugger.Break(); // never hits, so nothing is dropped
                    }
                    _lastSequence = message.Sequence;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class BaseMessage {
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product_id")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sequence")]
    public long Sequence { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you're absolutely correct. I conceptually misunderstood how the message sequencing works and assumed it was 'per subscription channel' (ie. ticker, match etc....) which obviously it isn't. What tripped me up is that sometimes messages came 'out of order' so I didn't immediately get the association between the sequences I was seeing.